# Analyze length of loops on network

Tags: spatial-analysis

I am working on a hiking network. Basically it is a selection of roads/paths suitable for walking/hiking. Each junction of three or four selected tracks is numbered. Each track is a line that starts and ends on a junction.

https://www.tov.be/nl/wandelrouteplanner

One of the criteria I have to fulfil is a minimum and maximum loop length on the selected tracks. If you do a hike from 1 to 2 to 3 to 1 again, it has to be between 3 and 5 km.

Is there a way to analyse the entire network to see which loops are too big and which are too small? How can I visualise this on map?

edit:

Perhaps it is possible to automatically merge the lines into loops. Most of the lines would be part of a couple of loops. Then I can calculate the length of the loops. After that I can colour the inside of the loops (transfer to polygons in the process?) to green for OK between 3 and 5 km and red if less then 3 or more than 5 km?